# `produce()` only called once in asynchronous kafka implementation?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-asyncio

I'm doing a simple kafka produce/consume test on the local machine using a docker.

docker-compose file: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml

And I've written a simple python code like below:

```py
import json
import random
import asyncio
from collections import namedtuple

from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroSerializer, AvroDeserializer
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import Schema
from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer, DeserializingConsumer

from faker import Faker
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict

faker = Faker()

registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient({"url": "http://localhost:8081"})


@dataclass
class CIS:
    user_id: str = field(default_factory=faker.user_name)
    question_id: int = field(default_factory=lambda: random.randint(1, 20000))
    is_correct: bool = field(default_factory=lambda: random.choice([True, False]))


async def produce(topic_name, serializer):
    p = SerializingProducer({
        "bootstrap.servers": "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092",
        "value.serializer": serializer
    })
    while True:
        p.produce(
            topic=topic_name,
            value=CIS(),
        )
        print("put!")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def consume(topic_name, deserialzier):
    c = DeserializingConsumer(
        {
            'bootstrap.servers': "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092",
            # 'key.deserializer': string_deserializer,
            'value.deserializer': deserialzier,
            'group.id': "123",
            'auto.offset.reset': "latest"
        }
    )
    c.subscribe([topic_name])
    while True:
        message = c.poll(0.1)
        if message is None:
            print(message)
            continue
        else:
            print(message.value())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    topic_name = "my_topic"
    schema_str = json.dumps(
        {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "cis",
            "namespace": "interaction",
            "fields": [
                {"name": "user_id", "type": "string"},
                {"name": "question_id", "type": "int"},
                {"name": "is_correct", "type": "boolean"}
            ]
        }
    )

    def to_dict(obj, ctx):
        return asdict(obj)

    def to_obj(obj, ctx):
        return CIS(
            user_id=obj["user_id"],
            question_id=obj["question_id"],
            is_correct=obj["is_correct"],
        )

    avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(registry_client, schema_str, to_dict)
    avro_deserializer = AvroDeserializer(registry_client, schema_str, to_obj)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t1 = loop.create_task(produce(topic_name, avro_serializer))
    t2 = loop.create_task(consume(topic_name, avro_deserializer))
    results = await asyncio.gather(t1, t2)
```

When I run this code, output is:

```
>>>
put!
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
....
```

I don't see why `produce()` is called only first time.

Comment: It’s the `continue` in `consume`. The only time you await anything is when there’s a message. When there isn’t one, you print out `None` and go back to `while True`.

Answer (score 0):

`confluent_kafka` is not asyncio compatible, it uses blocking calls.

For asyncio code I can suggest [aiokafka](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka). The project's README has code snippets that illustrates how to write async producer and consumer.